# Anjularjs add/register Controller dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

In my angular app, I have two pages. First page have static controller. Want to add Second page controller file  dynamically.

I tried to load JS file using this funcion

```
function loadJS() {        
        var jsElm = document.createElement("script"); 
        jsElm.type = "application/javascript";    
        jsElm.src = "TwoCtrl.js"; 
        document.body.appendChild(jsElm); 
}
```

It added controller js file to body. But I got undefined exception while redirect to second page. `Argument 'TwoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

TwoCtrl.js

```
app.controller('TwoCtrl', function (){

});
```

My config below. Please help. Thanks in advance!

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {  
    loadJS();
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html",
      controller: 'OneCtrl'
    })
    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "partials/state2.html",
      controller: 'TwoCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/OneCtrl");
});
```

Comment: you can't add controllers dynamically like this;  the controller has to be present during the config phase to be linked up to the state.  There are some 3rd party modules that try to circumvent this, with mixed results.  a google search for "angular lazy load" should turn up various attempts that have been made at the problem.